# Binary XML File, Error Inflating Class, What is the issue?

Tags: android, xml, binary

I'm getting this error when the application is changing layout. The resolution of the images are fine with other layouts but when it comes to this particular layout, it crashes. I tried using a simple design which was only colours for the layout and there wasn't any crashes. Hence, I would like to know if it's a memory issue or whether if it's a resolution issue. Please note that I am an inexperience android studio user and I would greatly appreciate if you can advise on the problem and whether if there is any solution

Logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fluke.kgwee.flukegame/com.fluke.kgwee.flukegame.endactivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Layout before app crashes:

```
<ViewFlipper
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:id="@+id/viewFlipper"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="175dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:background="@drawable/pq1"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:background="@drawable/pq2"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ViewFlipper>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="135dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="160dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:id="@+id/Prev"
        android:background="@drawable/leftarrow"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/buttonPrev" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:id="@+id/Next"
        android:background="@drawable/arrow"
        android:layout_marginLeft="230dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/buttonNext"
        android:clickable="true" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="135dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="275dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:background="@drawable/leftarrow"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
        android:background="@drawable/arrow"
        android:layout_marginLeft="230dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="135dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="385dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
        android:background="@drawable/leftarrow"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
        android:background="@drawable/arrow"
        android:layout_marginLeft="230dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Scoreboard:"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textColor="#010101"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="125dp"
    android:layout_height="125dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView13"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:background="@drawable/target1"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />
```

Comment: can you post your xml

Comment: Done. Posted, any solutions to solve the issue?

Comment: Have a look at the entire stacktrace, including the nested "caused by" exceptions.

Comment: It says that it is caused by this line         setContentView(R.layout.activity_endactivity);

Comment: Unable to post the whole nested exceptions due to restrictions

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 14745612 byte       allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 10MB until OOM

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be `OutOfMemoryError`.Check whether if you are loading large bitmaps in your Xml and get rid of that or manage properly

Answer (score 0):

Jas's answer is correct, to avoid try to run app in device not in emulator,
put smaller size images in drawable folder

Comment: But the background of the activity where the application is less than 100kb and the background which works perfectly fine is more than 100kb.